# Linking/including files to an existing .vcproj from another .vcproj

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, linker, header-files

I am using Visual studio 2008. I have a Visual C project "new.vcproj". There needed to be some changes made such that it utilizes class methods from another Visual C project "old.vcproj". The class is defined in class.hpp and implemented in class.cpp from project "old.vcproj" How can I include the class from "old" in the project "new"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `class.hpp` and `class.cpp` as existing items to the header and source parts of `new.vcproj`.

If `old.vcproj` compiles to a library, a better way would be to just include the header file `class.hpp` in your `new.vcproj` source files and and then link to the `old.vcproj` library.